# VB Script to replace text by using folder structure

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to VB Script. I am in need of VB Script to replace the specific text

Below is my file directory

1. E:\TEST\98\6549871\1959893\HTML
2. E:\TEST\98\6549871\1959793\HTML
3. E:\TEST\98\6549876\1959863\HTML
4. E:\TEST\96\6749473\6959895\HTML
5. E:\TEST\99\2548878\5959893\HTML

etc.,

Where in each HTML sub-folder, test.html and img.html page will contain. In that html pages I want to find the text **="img/** and needs to replace with **="/image/98/6549871/1959893/HTML/img/** where in **="/image/** is common for all files and remaining values are as per folder structure (i.e. 1st level folder name, 2nd level folder name, 3rd level folder name and 4th level folder name)

For every individual file I need to do like above, and taking too much time to do this activity.

Can any body help me on this to replace all **="img/** in a single shot base on the folder directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..not tested, but shoudl point you in the right direction

```
Option Explicit

Dim fileCount

Sub ProcessSubDirectory( ByVal directory)

On Error Resume Next

Dim fso
Dim dir
Dim folder
Dim file

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dir = fso.GetFolder(directory)

If Err.Number <> 0 THen
    MsgBox "Failed to open dir ( " & directory & " )"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Goto 0

For Each file in dir.Files
    Call HandleFileFix( file.Path )
Next

For Each folder in dir.SubFolders
    Call ProcessSubDirectory( folder.Path )
Next

Set fso = Nothing

End Sub

Sub HandleFileFix( ByVal file)

Dim fso
Dim f
Dim fo
Dim contents
DIm path

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo = fso.GetFile( file )
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile( file, 1 )

    path = fo.Path
    path = Replace( path, fo.Drive, "")
    path = Replace( path, fo.Name, "")
    path = Replace( path, "\", "/")

If f.AtEndOfStream = false then
    contents = f.ReadAll
End If

f.Close
Set f = Nothing

contents = Replace( contents, "='img/", "='" & path & "/img/")

' write file back to disk
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile( file, 2 )
f.Write contents
f.Close 
fileCount = fileCount + 1
Set f = Nothing

End Sub

fileCount = 0

Call ProcessSubDirectory( "D:\TEST\" )

MsgBox "done (" & CStr(fileCount) & ")"
```

Comment: -0.49 for posting untested code that fails because folder.Name (instead of .Path) is passed to ProcessSubDirectory. (This blunder proves again that passing pathes/string instead of folders/objects in directory traversal is a bad idea.)

Comment: test in dummy folder. showing error at replace stage. since it is not accepting to find ="/img and replace with ="image/98/6549871/1959893/HTML/img/

Comment: Hi, tested, but showing error msg at line 64 char 1 error Invalid procedure call or argument